# Make marker with text and path in Google maps ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocoa-touch, google-maps-markers

I want to make the marker as the photo in google maps. It has 1 circle with some text, and 1 rectangle with text. Do i need to draw it? How can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as an image and make a custom marker. To see how to make a custom marker, you can read about it over [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#change_the_default_marker_icon).